# i need to send a email from azure data factory .net activity C# code

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, azure-data-factory

i am running .net activity in azure data lake store using C#, i need to send a email based on my job fail or pass or writing some logger information.

i know on-perm  we have option DBmail, SMTP but in data factory

Regards,
Manish

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-monitor-manage-app#create-alerts

Comment: Thanks for replay, i need to send email from within C# code where any exception will rise.

Comment: Ah my bad. Maybe you can use SendGrid? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email